# Using javascript reduce to filter an array of objects, to find the lowest calculated stats

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I wrote this for loop

```
if (specimins.length > 0) {
    var max = specimins[0]
    for (var x = 1; x < specimins.length; x++) {
        if ((max.weight+max.height) > (specimins[x].weight+specimins[x].height)) {
            max = specimins[x]
        }
    }
    specimins = [max]
}
```

However, it is quite an eyesore. So basically, it is going over an array of of specimens to find the lowest total amount calculated weight + height. Is there are a good way to have this use array.reduce()? I have tried some attempts but most of it never works for me.

Any help is a appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I don't consider this an 'eyesore' its important to remember that syntactic sugar is not always a better choice because it is fewer lines of code. You may be sacrificing readability for brevity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the element with the lowest height + width using `reduce` as follows:

```
var max = specimens.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return (a.width + a.height) < (b.width + b.height) ? a : b
}, specimens[0])
```

However, there is nothing wrong with using a standard for loop in this case.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the edit, though I'm a bit suspicious of calling the *lowest* variable `max` :)

Comment: Yeah, just thought the variable should named the same as in the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! That max is left over from something else, thanks for pointing that out too @Damon gonna change that right now. Cheers!

Comment: @Neal no problem, would appreciate if you pick my answer as "accepted answer"